# What is "And Voila!"?

Tags: word-usage

Hello everyone I was see this in one question Stack Overflow :

> And Voila!

I asked me that i mean ? I looked in internet [this definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=And%20Voila%21) :

> A way of saying "It's just that simple": *In Phone sex as a career, all I got to do is say a few thing and moan ...And Voila! I got money in no time. I don't even have to touch myself either while having Phone sex.*

but I don't know in what situation I can use this?  anyone can say me where I can use this?

Comment: The implication of the phrase is that you do something, and _like magic_, something else happens - in your phone sex example, "... all I got to do is say a few things and moan ... and _like magic_, I got money in no time. ..."

Comment: If English is not your native language, it might help if you identified what your native language is - so that perhaps another speaker of that language can express this "English" idiom (actually stolen from French) in terms of a similar idiom from your language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literally, "voilà!" is French for "look at that!" As commenter @JeffZeitlin says, it has a connotation of a sudden and magical revelation - you've just pulled aside the curtain and revealed something amazing and said, "And look at that!"

The urban dictionary definition is a bit misleading.  It can be used when a situation is "just that simple," but you're saying, "And voilà!" in that case because it's *amazing* that it's simple, not just that it's simple.

Imagine that you had prepared a really fancy dinner for your girlfriend.  You tell her to close her eyes and you lead her into the dining room.  You might say, "Now open your eyes...and voilà!"  In this case you're not trying to say that preparing dinner was simple; what you're saying is that you're revealing an amazing and almost magical thing (a special dinner).

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to be super sophisticated you would say, in your best imitation French accent, *Et voilà!*  That way your girlfriend knows you are a really classy guy.  :)

Answer (score 0):

"Voila" is an interjection used to call attention to something. It is typically used in magic acts: the magician performs some trick, and then announces, "Voila! The rabbit has disappeared" or whatever. Maybe magicians today consider this a tired cliche and rarely use it anymore, but that's the context English speakers think of this word in.

It can be used in other cases to call attention to some result. Like, "And then we pour the sauce over the meat, and voila! a delicious dinner in ten minutes!" In general the idea is, "almost magical".